# Continuous playback in chromecast receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I need to implement continuous playback in my google cast custom receiver. For that I am handling the video event 'ended' after playing my first content, and I have to make an API call there to get the next content's media url. And now I am confusing about how can I restart playing with my new content.

Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what format/type of media are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize MediaQueueItem (and .Builder as well) to create queue items before its being played (essentially a playlist itself). RemoteMediaPlayer.queueLoad is already used by the VideoCastManager to load and start a new queue of media items.